# how to rotate image in File in C# & WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, image, transformation

I have WPF and C# application. which captures the images and Save in to file(*.jpg).
I have the image path and i want to rotate image saved in File through the c# code.
and Save the Rotated image in same file.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [rotate flip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

E.g.:

```
        Bitmap bitmap1 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\test.jpg");
        bitmap1.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
        bitmap1.Save(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\test rotated.jpg");
```

Comment: Add Reference `System.Drawing` to project. add `using System.Drawing;` and then add above code.

Comment: 'bitmap1.Save(@"C:\Documents and Settings\" + 
        @"All Users\Documents\My Music\music.jpg"); '

add this to code working Bro!!! Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

you can use my method:

```
    BitmapImage rotateImage(string filename,int angle)
    {
        WIA.ImageFile img = new WIA.ImageFile();
        img.LoadFile(filename);

        WIA.ImageProcess IP = new WIA.ImageProcess();

        Object ix1 = (Object)"RotateFlip";
        WIA.FilterInfo fi1 = IP.FilterInfos.get_Item(ref ix1);
        IP.Filters.Add(fi1.FilterID, 0);

        Object p1 = (Object)"RotationAngle";
        Object pv1 = (Object)angle;
        IP.Filters[1].Properties.get_Item(ref p1).set_Value(ref pv1);

        img = IP.Apply(img);

        File.Delete(filename);
        img.SaveFile(filename);


        BitmapImage imagetemp = new BitmapImage();
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            imagetemp.BeginInit();
            imagetemp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            imagetemp.StreamSource = stream;
            imagetemp.EndInit();
        }

        return imagetemp;
    }
```

usage:

```
        string filename = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "4.jpg";

        image.Source = rotateImage(filename,90);
```